# list contact information in two line ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-contacts, android-cursor, android-contentresolver

I want to list contact details (name of the person, number of the person) in a two line `ListView` (first line: name of the person, second line: phone number). I sucessfully get all necessary information of the contacts, but I have got problems to list them in the `ListView`. Just the first contact is shown in the `ListView`.

in `onCreate()` I create the `ContentResolver` Object, call the method `get_list( )` to get name and phone number and try to display the `ListView`:

```
 ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    int anzahl = cur.getCount();
    Log.d("anzahl09", "anzahl09 " + anzahl);

    telefonname = new String[anzahl];
    telefonnummer = new String[anzahl];
    zusammengesetzt = new String[anzahl];

    kontakte_laden = new String[anzahl][anzahl];

    String[] telefonname_telefonnummer = new String[anzahl];
    telefonname_telefonnummer = get_list(cur, cr);

    int i =0;
    do {
        Log.d("schleife09", "schleife09 " + i + "|" + telefonname_telefonnummer[i] + "|" +  telefonname[i] + "|" + telefonnummer[i] + "|" + kontakte_laden[i][i]);
        kontakte_laden[i][0] = telefonname[i];
        kontakte_laden[i][1] = telefonnummer[i];
        i++;
    } while (i < anzahl);


    ListView listview = ( ListView ) findViewById ( android.R.id.list );

    listview.setPadding ( 20, 20, 20, 20 );

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Diamond") ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > > list = new ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > > ();


    for (String[] anAussehen : kontakte_laden) {
        //noinspection Convert2Diamond
        item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item.put("line1", anAussehen[0]);
        item.put("line2", anAussehen[1]);
        list.add(item);
    }


    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            new String[]{"line1", "line2"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});


    listview.setAdapter(sa);


    listview.setOnItemClickListener(listViewOnItemClickListener);
```

The method, which read contact information `get_list()` looks like this:

```
 private String[] get_list(Cursor cur, ContentResolver cr){

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            int i=0;
            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            telefonname[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.d("telefonname09", "telefonname09 " +telefonname[i]);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        telefonnummer[i] = pCur.getString( pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER ) );
                        Log.d("telefonnummer09", "telefonnummer09 " + telefonnummer[i]); // correct values
                    }
                    pCur.close();
                }
            }

            zusammengesetzt[i] = telefonname[i] + "|" + telefonnummer[i];
        }
    }



// only one value
        for(int i=0; i < cur.getCount(); i++){
            Log.d("telefonnummer07", "telefonnummer07 " + telefonname[i] + "|" + telefonnummer[i]);
        }
    cur.close();
    return zusammengesetzt;
}
```

But the result is the following: 
[image]

**UPDATE**
The problem is, that the arrays for name of the person (`telefonname[]`) and for the phone number (`telefonnummer[]`) only have got in the while-loop of the `get_list()` method the correct content. Outside of the while-loop the arrays have got only the last value. See the method `get_list()` above.

**SOLUTION**
I changed following points:

- I defined the number and the name to the global String arrays directly before. So in the `get_list()` method I had to define two new String arrays
- I refer the name and the phone number to these new local String arrays
- refer these new local String arrays to the global String arrays

This is the working code:

The `onCreate()` method:

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


    int anzahl = cur.getCount();
    Log.d("anzahl09", "anzahl09 " + anzahl);

    telefonname_global = new String[anzahl];
    telefonnummer_global = new String[anzahl];


    kontakte_laden = new String[anzahl][anzahl];

    get_list(cur, cr);


    int i =0;
    do {
        Log.d("schleife09", "schleife09 " + i + "|" /*+ telefonname_telefonnummer[i] + "|" */ +  telefonname_global[i] + "|" + telefonnummer_global[i] + "|" + kontakte_laden[i][i]);
        kontakte_laden[i][0] = telefonname_global[i];
        kontakte_laden[i][1] = telefonnummer_global[i];
        i++;
    } while (i < anzahl);


    ListView listview = ( ListView ) findViewById ( android.R.id.list );

    listview.setPadding ( 20, 20, 20, 20 );

    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Diamond") ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > > list = new ArrayList< HashMap< String, String > > ();


    for (String[] anAussehen : kontakte_laden) {
        //noinspection Convert2Diamond
        item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item.put("line1", anAussehen[0]);
        item.put("line2", anAussehen[1]);
        list.add(item);
    }


    SimpleAdapter sa = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            new String[]{"line1", "line2"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});


    listview.setAdapter(sa);



    listview.setOnItemClickListener(listViewOnItemClickListener);
```

And the `get_list()` method:

```
private void get_list(Cursor cur, ContentResolver cr){

    int i = 0;

    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        String[] telefonname = new String[cur.getCount()];
        String[] telefonnummer = new String[cur.getCount()];


        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            telefonname[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Log.d("telefonname09", "telefonname09 " +telefonname[i]);

            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);

                    while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                        telefonnummer[i] = pCur.getString( pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER ) );
                        Log.d("telefonnummer09", "telefonnummer09 " + telefonnummer[i]);
                    }

                    pCur.close();
                }
            }

            Log.d("telefonnummer08", "telefonnummer08 " + telefonnummer[i]);
            telefonname_global[i] = telefonname[i];
            telefonnummer_global[i] = telefonnummer[i];

            i++;
        }
    }

    // Fehler: Array telefonnummer hat nur einen Wert
    for(int j=0; j < cur.getCount(); j++){
        Log.d("telefonnummer07", "telefonnummer07 " + telefonname_global[j] + "|" + telefonnummer_global[j]);
    }


     cur.close();

}
```

Thanks a lot for helping.

One other problem is, that e-mail adresses or contacts without phone number shouldn't be in this list. How to achieve this?

Comment: thanks for your comment. No exception occurs. And the values of name, number of the get_list() method are correct.

Comment: If you are saying that your get_list() method is correct then apparently
there is no mistake here, but what is the size of your adapter, have you checked that?

Comment: please see my edited post

Comment: move the cursor to first row. cursor.moveToFirst()

Comment: you mean before while(cursor.moveToNext() )? The result is, that no content is shown anymore

Comment: hi @user3603935 see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i is not increment that is the problem

```
private String[] get_list(Cursor cur, ContentResolver cr){

if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
   // inialize outside
    int i=0;
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {

        String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        telefonname[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        Log.d("telefonname09", "telefonname09 " +telefonname[i]);

        if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    telefonnummer[i] = pCur.getString( pCur.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER ) );
                    Log.d("telefonnummer09", "telefonnummer09 " + telefonnummer[i]); // correct values
                }
                pCur.close();
            }
        }

        zusammengesetzt[i] = telefonname[i] + "|" + telefonnummer[i];

       //i is need to increment
       i++;
    }
}
```

add only if phone number exist

```
 for (String[] anAussehen : kontakte_laden) {
  if(anAussehen[1] != null)
  {
    //noinspection Convert2Diamond
    item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("line1", anAussehen[0]);
    item.put("line2", anAussehen[1]);
    list.add(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You are right I forget the increment of i. But unfortunately the result is the same.

Comment: move the i declaration before the while loop start

Comment: I found the solution for this problem and edited my post. Thanks a lot for helping. But there is an other problem: I don't want to display e-mail adresses and contacts without phone number. How to achieve this?

Comment: @user3603935 I updated the code if only phone number exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have ended my searching for fastest solution to retrieve from Android Phone. ContactDTO is the pojo class.

It will return result in ascending order of "Contact Display Name".

```
public static List<ContactDTO> getPhone(Context context){
            List<ContactDTO> contactList = new ArrayList<ContactDTO>();
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver(); 
            String[] PROJECTION = new String[] { 
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID, 
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID };

            Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
            String filter = ""+ ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > 0 and " + Phone.TYPE +"=" + Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;     
            String order = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";// LIMIT " + limit + " offset " + lastId + "";

            Cursor phoneCur = cr.query(uri, PROJECTION, filter, null, order);
            while(phoneCur.moveToNext()){
                 ContactDTO dto = new ContactDTO();
                 dto.setName("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                 dto.setMobileNo("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)));
                 dto.setPhotoUrl("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI)));
                 dto.setContactId("" + phoneCur.getString(phoneCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTACT_ID)));
                 contactList.add(dto);
             }
             phoneCur.close();
            return contactList;
}
```